# Asymptotic expansion of integral involving an ArcTan

Tags: functions, definite-integrals, asymptotics, approximation

The function I want to study reads
$$
f(y)= \frac{\sqrt{1+y^2}}{\pi^2 y} \int_0^\infty du \left\lbrace \arctan \left[\frac{2y}{u^2(1+y^2)+1-y^2 }\right] \right\rbrace^2 \, ,
$$
and it is well-defined for any real $y$ (actually the integral diverges for $y=0$, but this divergence is tamed by the prefactor so that $f(0)=0$, and $f(y)\simeq y/\pi$ for small $y$).

By computing the integral numerically I learn that
$$
\lim_{y\to \infty}f(y) = 1 \, ,
$$
so I am interested in its asymptotic behavior for large $y$, like
$$f(y)\simeq 1-g(y) \, ,$$
for some function $g(y)$ (vanishing in the limit $y\to\infty$) which I want to determine. Clearly a blind Taylor expansion does not work, because not all the terms in the series converge.

Do you have any suggestion?

EDIT:

The branch of the $ArcTan$ is chosen so that it returns a number in $[0,\pi]$.

EDIT 2:

To further clarify which branch of the $ArcTan$ I am interested in, here I am plotting the integrand $ArcTan$ (without squaring it) for two sample values of $y$. For $y=1$, in particular, the argument of $ArcTan$ is always positive, so it returns $\pi/2$ at $u=0$ and then it decays to zero at large $u$.

[image: Plot of the integrand ArcTan.]

With this choice, $f(y)$ grows monotonically from $0$ to $1$, with no peak (and no other surprises) in the middle.

Comment: $f(y)\to 0$ at $y\to\infty$. I got the main asymptotics term $f(y)\sim \frac{2\ln2}{\pi y}$ at $y\to\infty$. Numeric evaluation confirms this behavior. At $y=10\,\, f(10)=0.04375...;\, \frac{2\ln2}{10\pi}=0.04412...\,$ At $y=20\,\, f(20)=0.02201...;\,\frac{2\ln2}{20\pi}=0.02206...$

Comment: @Svyatoslav are you using Mathematica to compute the integral numerically? If so, note that `ArcTan[y/x]` and `ArcTan[x,y]` are two very different functions. The former is the principal branch of the complex ArcTan, and it is not what I'm talking about here.

Comment: @Svyatoslav I think that the choice of the branch is very important here. With your choice, you always get an angle in $[-\pi /2, \pi /2]$, while my ArcTan comes from a Physics problem — the angle needs to be cast in the right quadrant depending on the relative signs of numerator and denominator. Maybe the function is not defined properly, but is what I mean clear?

Comment: @DavideVenturelli How is your $\arctan$ related to the principal branch? Can you provide a precise definition?

Comment: For large $y$, I think we need $\arctan \to \pi+ \tan^{-1}$ when $u<1$ and $\arctan \to \tan^{-1}$ when $u>1$ where $\tan^{-1}$ is the principle branch taking values in $-\pi/2, \pi/2$

Comment: Svyatoslav Sal @Gary thanks for your efforts! Are my two edits answering your questions?

Comment: @DavideVenturelli Your function is the principal branch of the [inverse cotangent](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseCotangent.html). You can use $\cot^{-1}(z)=\tan^{-1}(1/z)$ though.

Comment: @Gary I have to disagree, I specified that it is a number in $[0,\pi]$ -- in particular, it is never negative (see my plot). However (forgive me, I am a brute physicist), the precise definition of the function is useful to me only insofar as it clarifies the question (and I'm not sure if it's actually serving the purpose).

Comment: @Svyatoslav ok, I'm glad that we converged on a common understanding of what this function is. But how could I access the behavior of $f(y)$ beyond its leading order, that is, the function $g(y)$ in my question?

Comment: $$f(y)=1-\frac{2}{\pi}\,\frac{(\ln y+1)}{y}+O\Big(\frac{\ln y}{y^{3/2}}\Big)$$
If the answer is OK, I will post the solution.

Comment: @Svyatoslav I tested it numerically and it seems to work very well, and already at small values of $y$... great, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this problem we define
$$\arctan x=\operatorname{Arctan}x, \,\text{at}\,x>0$$
$$\arctan x=\pi-\operatorname{Arctan}|x|, \,\text{at}\,x<0$$
where $\operatorname{Arctan}x$ denotes the main branch $(\operatorname{Arctan}x=0\,\text{at}\,x=0\,\,\text{and}\,\operatorname{Arctan}x=\frac{\pi}{2}\,\text{at}\,x\to\infty\,)$.

Then
$$f(y)= \frac{\sqrt{1+y^2}}{\pi^2 y} \int_0^\infty \left\lbrace \arctan \left[\frac{2y}{u^2(1+y^2)+1-y^2 }\right] \right\rbrace^2du$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{1+y^2}}{\pi^2 y}\int_1^\infty \left\lbrace \arctan \left[\frac{2y}{(1+y^2)\big(u^2-\frac{y^2-1}{y^2+1}\big) }\right] \right\rbrace^2du$$
$$+\frac{\sqrt{1+y^2}}{\pi^2 y}\int_0^1 \left\lbrace \pi-\arctan \left[\frac{2y}{(1+y^2)\big(\frac{y^2-1}{y^2+1}-u^2\big) }\right] \right\rbrace^2du$$
Dropping the terms which bring additional factor $\sim\frac{1}{y^2}$, we can simplify the integral. The form of the first asymptotics terms will confirm the chosen approach.

For example,
$$ \frac{\sqrt{1+y^2}}{\pi^2 y}=\frac{1}{\pi^2}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{y^2}}=\frac{1}{\pi^2}\Big(1+\frac{1}{2y^2}+...\Big)$$
$$\frac{y^2-1}{y^2+1}-u^2=1-u^2-\frac{2}{y^2}-...\,\text{and}\,\,\frac{2y}{1+y^2}=\frac{2}{y}\Big(1-\frac{1}{y^2}+..\Big)$$
So, for the main asymptotics we use the following representation:
$$\pi^2f(y)\sim\int_1^\infty \left\lbrace \arctan \left[\frac{2}{y(u^2-1) }\right] \right\rbrace^2du+\int_0^1 \left\lbrace\pi- \arctan \left[\frac{2}{y(1-u^2) }\right] \right\rbrace^2du$$
Making the substitution $x=u^2$ and opening parentheses
$$=\pi^2+\frac{1}{2}\int_1^\infty\arctan^2\Big(\frac{2}{y(x-1)}\Big)\frac{dx}{\sqrt x}-\pi\int_0^1\arctan\Big(\frac{2}{y(1-x)}\Big)\frac{dx}{\sqrt x}$$
$$+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\arctan^2\Big(\frac{2}{y(1-x)}\Big)\frac{dx}{\sqrt x}=\pi^2+I_1+I_2+I_3\tag{1}$$
Now we will evaluate every term.
$$I_1=\frac{1}{2}\int_1^\infty\arctan^2\Big(\frac{2}{y(x-1)}\Big)\frac{dx}{\sqrt x}=\frac{1}{y}\int_0^\infty\arctan^2\frac{1}{t}\,\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2t}{y}}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{y}\int_0^\infty\arctan^2\Big(\frac{1}{t}\Big)dt-\frac{1}{y}\int_0^\infty\arctan^2\Big(\frac{1}{t}\Big)\bigg(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2t}{y}}}\bigg)dt\tag 2$$
Integrating by part a couple of times, it is not difficult to evaluate the  first integral in $(2)$
$$I_{1,1}=\frac{1}{y}\int_0^\infty\arctan^2\Big(\frac{1}{t}\Big)dt=\frac{1}{y}\int_0^\infty\frac{\arctan^2x}{x^2}dx=\frac{\pi\ln2}{y}\tag 3$$
The second integral in $(2)$:
$$I_{1,2}=\frac{1}{y}\int_0^\infty\arctan^2\Big(\frac{1}{t}\Big)\bigg(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2t}{y}}}\bigg)dt$$
$$=\frac{2}{y^2}\int_0^\infty\arctan^2\Big(\frac{1}{t}\Big)\frac{tdt}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2t}{y}}\Big(1+\sqrt{1+\frac{2t}{y}}\Big)}$$
To estimate it, let's split the interval of integration $[0;\sqrt\frac{y}{2}\,];\,[\sqrt\frac{y}{2};\infty)$. Making the substitution $t=\frac{1}{x}$
$$\frac{2}{y^2}\int_0^\sqrt\frac{y}{2}\arctan^2\Big(\frac{1}{t}\Big)\frac{tdt}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2t}{y}}\Big(1+\sqrt{1+\frac{2t}{y}}\Big)}<\frac{2}{y^2}\int_0^\sqrt\frac{y}{2}\arctan^2\Big(\frac{1}{t}\Big)\frac{tdt}{2}$$
$$=\frac{1}{y^2}\int_\sqrt\frac{2}{y}^\infty\frac{\arctan^2x}{x^3}dx=O\Big(\frac{\ln y}{y^2}\Big)$$
At the same time,
$$\frac{2}{y^2}\int_\sqrt\frac{y}{2}^\infty\arctan^2\Big(\frac{1}{t}\Big)\frac{tdt}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2t}{y}}\Big(1+\sqrt{1+\frac{2t}{y}}\Big)}<\frac{2}{y^2}\int_\sqrt\frac{y}{2}^\infty\frac{dt}{t\sqrt{1+\frac{2t}{y}}\Big(1+\sqrt{1+\frac{2t}{y}}\Big)}$$
Making the substitution $t=\frac{xy}{2}$
$$=\frac{2}{y^2}\int_\sqrt\frac{2}{y}^\infty\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{1+x}(1+\sqrt{1+x})}<\frac{2}{y^2}\int_\sqrt\frac{2}{y}^\infty\frac{dx}{x(1+x)}=O\Big(\frac{\ln y}{y^2}\Big)$$
Therefore,
$$\boxed{\,\,I_1=\frac{\pi\ln2}{y}+O\Big(\frac{\ln y}{y^2}\Big)\,\,}\tag 4$$
In the same way we evaluate $I_3$. Using $(3)$, after some manipulations we finally get
$$I_3=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\arctan^2\Big(\frac{2}{y(1-x)}\Big)\frac{dx}{\sqrt x}=\frac{1}{y}\int_0^\frac{y}{2}\frac{\arctan^2\big(\frac{1}{t}\big)}{\sqrt{1-\frac{2t}{y}}}dt$$
$$=\frac{1}{y}\int_0^\infty\arctan^2\Big(\frac{1}{t}\Big)dt+O\Big(\frac{\ln y}{y^2}\Big)+O\Big(\frac{1}{y^{3/2}}\Big)$$
$$\boxed{\,\,I_3=\frac{\pi\ln2}{y}+O\Big(\frac{1}{y^{3/2}}\Big)\,\,}\tag 5$$
The most interesting story is with $I_2$
$$I_2=-\pi\int_0^1\arctan\Big(\frac{2}{y(1-x)}\Big)\frac{dx}{\sqrt x}=-\frac{2\pi}{y}\int_0^\frac{y}{2}\frac{\arctan\big(\frac{1}{t}\big)}{\sqrt{1-\frac{2t}{y}}}dt$$
Integrating by part
$$=-\frac{2\pi}{y}\bigg(\frac{\pi y}{2}-y\int_0^\frac{y}{2}\frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{2t}{y}}}{1+t^2}dt\bigg)$$
After some manipulations, using $\frac{\pi}{2}=\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{1+t^2}$, and integrating by part one more time
$$I_2\sim-\frac{2\pi}{y}\bigg(2+\ln\Big(1+\frac{y^2}{4}\Big)-\frac{1}{y}\int_0^\frac{y}{2}\frac{\ln(1+t^2)}{\sqrt{1-\frac{2t}{y}}\big(1+\sqrt{1-\frac{2t}{y}}\big)}dt\bigg)$$
$$=-\frac{2\pi}{y}\bigg(2+\ln\Big(1+\frac{y^2}{4}\Big)-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{\ln\Big(1+\frac{y^2}{4}x^2\Big)}{\sqrt{1-x}\big(1+\sqrt{1-x}\big)}dx\bigg)$$
To evaluate the remaining integral, again we split the interval of integration $[0;\sqrt\frac{2}{y}\,];\,[\sqrt\frac{2}{y};1]$. Integration over the first interval gives $O\Big(\frac{\ln y}{y^{3/2}}\Big)$; integration over the second interval gives the main terms. Skipping intermediate steps, we get:
$$I_2\sim-\frac{2\pi}{y}\bigg(2+2\ln\frac{y}{2}-\int_0^1\frac{\ln x+\ln\frac{y}{2}}{\sqrt{1-x}\big(1+\sqrt{1-x}\big)^2}dx\bigg)$$
$$=-\frac{2\pi}{y}\bigg(2+2\ln\frac{y}{2}-2\int_0^1\frac{\ln (1-t^2)}{\big(1+t\big)^2}dx-2\ln\frac{y}{2}\int_0^1\frac{dt}{\big(1+t\big)^2}\bigg)$$
$$=-\frac{2\pi}{y}\bigg(2+2\ln\frac{y}{2}+2\ln2-1-\ln\frac{y}{2}\bigg)$$
$$\boxed{\,\,I_2=-\frac{2\pi}{y}\big(1+\ln2+\ln y\big)+O\Big(\frac{\ln y}{y^{3/2}}\Big)\,\,}\tag 6$$
Now, putting $(4)$, $(5)$ and $(6)$ into $(1)$
$$\boxed{\boxed{\,\,f(y)=1-\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{(\ln y+1)}{y}+O\Big(\frac{\ln y}{y^{3/2}}\Big)\,\,}}$$

Answer (score 5):

---

Define the function $\mathcal{I}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ via the (convergent) improper integral

$$\mathcal{I}{\left(z\right)}:=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}u\,\left[\arctan{\left(\frac{2z}{\left(1+z^{2}\right)u^{2}+1-z^{2}}\right)}\right]^{2}.$$

It is actually possible to obtain a closed form expression for $\mathcal{I}$ in terms of elementary functions. Since this is perhaps unexpected, I thought I'd post a solution.

---

Suppose $z\in\mathbb{R}$, and set $\arctan{\left(z\right)}=:\theta\in\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\implies z=\tan{\left(\theta\right)}$. Then,

$$\frac{2z}{1+z^{2}}=\sin{\left(2\theta\right)},$$

$$\frac{1-z^{2}}{1+z^{2}}=\cos{\left(2\theta\right)},$$

and so

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(z\right)}
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}u\,\left[\arctan{\left(\frac{2z}{\left(1+z^{2}\right)u^{2}+1-z^{2}}\right)}\right]^{2}\\
\implies\mathcal{I}{\left(\tan{\left(\theta\right)}\right)}
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}u\,\left[\arctan{\left(\frac{\sin{\left(2\theta\right)}}{u^{2}+\cos{\left(2\theta\right)}}\right)}\right]^{2}\\
&=\lim_{u\to\infty}\left[u\arctan^{2}{\left(\frac{\sin{\left(2\theta\right)}}{u^{2}+\cos{\left(2\theta\right)}}\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~-\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}u\,u\frac{d}{du}\left[\arctan{\left(\frac{\sin{\left(2\theta\right)}}{u^{2}+\cos{\left(2\theta\right)}}\right)}\right]^{2};~~~\small{I.B.P.}\\
&=-\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}u\,u\left[-\frac{4u\sin{\left(2\theta\right)}}{u^{4}+2u^{2}\cos{\left(2\theta\right)}+1}\arctan{\left(\frac{\sin{\left(2\theta\right)}}{u^{2}+\cos{\left(2\theta\right)}}\right)}\right]\\
&=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2u^{2}\sin{\left(2\theta\right)}}{u^{4}+2u^{2}\cos{\left(2\theta\right)}+1}\arctan{\left(\frac{\sin{\left(2\theta\right)}}{u^{2}+\cos{\left(2\theta\right)}}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2u^{2}\sin{\left(2\theta\right)}}{u^{4}+2u^{2}\cos{\left(2\theta\right)}+1}\arctan{\left(\frac{\sin{\left(2\theta\right)}}{u^{2}+\cos{\left(2\theta\right)}}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{-\infty}^{0}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2u^{2}\sin{\left(2\theta\right)}}{u^{4}+2u^{2}\cos{\left(2\theta\right)}+1}\arctan{\left(\frac{\sin{\left(2\theta\right)}}{u^{2}+\cos{\left(2\theta\right)}}\right)};~~~\small{\left[u\mapsto-u\right]}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2u^{2}\sin{\left(2\theta\right)}}{u^{4}+2u^{2}\cos{\left(2\theta\right)}+1}\arctan{\left(\frac{\sin{\left(2\theta\right)}}{u^{2}+\cos{\left(2\theta\right)}}\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

Given $\theta\in\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\land u\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $u^{2}+\cos{\left(2\theta\right)}\neq0$, we can show that

$$\begin{align}
\arctan{\left(\frac{\sin{\left(2\theta\right)}}{u^{2}+\cos{\left(2\theta\right)}}\right)}
&=\arctan{\left(\frac{\sin{\left(2\theta\right)}}{u^{2}+\cos{\left(2\theta\right)}}\right)}-\lim_{v\to\infty}\arctan{\left(\frac{\sin{\left(2\theta\right)}}{v^{2}+\cos{\left(2\theta\right)}}\right)}\\
&=-\int_{u}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{d}{dv}\arctan{\left(\frac{\sin{\left(2\theta\right)}}{v^{2}+\cos{\left(2\theta\right)}}\right)}\\
&=-\int_{u}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{(-1)2v\sin{\left(2\theta\right)}}{v^{4}+2v^{2}\cos{\left(2\theta\right)}+1}\\
&=\int_{u}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{2v\sin{\left(2\theta\right)}}{v^{4}+2v^{2}\cos{\left(2\theta\right)}+1}\\
&=\int_{u}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{4v\sin{\left(\theta\right)}\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}{\left[v^{2}-2v\sin{\left(\theta\right)}+1\right]\left[v^{2}+2v\sin{\left(\theta\right)}+1\right]}\\
&=\int_{u}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}v\,\left[\frac{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}{v^{2}-2v\sin{\left(\theta\right)}+1}-\frac{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}{v^{2}+2v\sin{\left(\theta\right)}+1}\right]\\
&=\int_{u}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}{v^{2}-2v\sin{\left(\theta\right)}+1}-\int_{u}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}{v^{2}+2v\sin{\left(\theta\right)}+1}\\
&=\int_{u-\sin{\left(\theta\right)}}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}{w^{2}+\cos^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}}-\int_{u+\sin{\left(\theta\right)}}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}{w^{2}+\cos^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}}\\
&=\int_{u-\sin{\left(\theta\right)}}^{u+\sin{\left(\theta\right)}}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}{w^{2}+\cos^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}}\\
&=\int_{\frac{u-\sin{\left(\theta\right)}}{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}}^{\frac{u+\sin{\left(\theta\right)}}{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{x^{2}+1}\\
&=\arctan{\left(\frac{u+\sin{\left(\theta\right)}}{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}\right)}-\arctan{\left(\frac{u-\sin{\left(\theta\right)}}{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

It can also be shown that

$$u^{4}+2u^{2}\cos{\left(2\theta\right)}+1=\left[u^{2}-2u\sin{\left(\theta\right)}+1\right]\left[u^{2}+2u\sin{\left(\theta\right)}+1\right];~~~\small{(u,\theta)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}}.$$

Then, for $\theta\in\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ we have

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(\tan{\left(\theta\right)}\right)}
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2u^{2}\sin{\left(2\theta\right)}}{u^{4}+2u^{2}\cos{\left(2\theta\right)}+1}\arctan{\left(\frac{\sin{\left(2\theta\right)}}{u^{2}+\cos{\left(2\theta\right)}}\right)}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2u^{2}\sin{\left(2\theta\right)}}{\left[u^{2}-2u\sin{\left(\theta\right)}+1\right]\left[u^{2}+2u\sin{\left(\theta\right)}+1\right]}\\
&~~~~~\times\left[\arctan{\left(\frac{u+\sin{\left(\theta\right)}}{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}\right)}-\arctan{\left(\frac{u-\sin{\left(\theta\right)}}{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}\right)}\right]\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}u\,\left[\frac{u\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}{u^{2}-2u\sin{\left(\theta\right)}+1}-\frac{u\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}{u^{2}+2u\sin{\left(\theta\right)}+1}\right]\\
&~~~~~\times\left[\arctan{\left(\frac{\sin{\left(\theta\right)}+u}{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}\right)}+\arctan{\left(\frac{\sin{\left(\theta\right)}-u}{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}\right)}\right]\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{u\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}{u^{2}-2u\sin{\left(\theta\right)}+1}\left[\arctan{\left(\frac{\sin{\left(\theta\right)}+u}{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}\right)}+\arctan{\left(\frac{\sin{\left(\theta\right)}-u}{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{u\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}{u^{2}+2u\sin{\left(\theta\right)}+1}\left[\arctan{\left(\frac{\sin{\left(\theta\right)}+u}{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}\right)}+\arctan{\left(\frac{\sin{\left(\theta\right)}-u}{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}\right)}\right]\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{u\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}{u^{2}-2u\sin{\left(\theta\right)}+1}\left[\arctan{\left(\frac{\sin{\left(\theta\right)}+u}{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}\right)}+\arctan{\left(\frac{\sin{\left(\theta\right)}-u}{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{u\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}{u^{2}-2u\sin{\left(\theta\right)}+1}\\
&~~~~~\times\left[\arctan{\left(\frac{\sin{\left(\theta\right)}-u}{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}\right)}+\arctan{\left(\frac{\sin{\left(\theta\right)}+u}{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}\right)}\right];~~~\small{\left[u\mapsto-u\right]}\\
&=2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{u\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}{u^{2}-2u\sin{\left(\theta\right)}+1}\left[\arctan{\left(\frac{\sin{\left(\theta\right)}+u}{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}\right)}+\arctan{\left(\frac{\sin{\left(\theta\right)}-u}{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}\right)}\right]\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2u\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}{u^{2}-2u\sin{\left(\theta\right)}+1}\left[\arctan{\left(\frac{u+\sin{\left(\theta\right)}}{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}\right)}-\arctan{\left(\frac{u-\sin{\left(\theta\right)}}{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}\right)}\right]\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{2\left[v+\sin{\left(\theta\right)}\right]\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}{v^{2}+\cos^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}}\\
&~~~~~\times\left[\arctan{\left(\frac{v+2\sin{\left(\theta\right)}}{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}\right)}-\arctan{\left(\frac{v}{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}\right)}\right];~~~\small{\left[u=v+\sin{\left(\theta\right)}\right]}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{2\cos{\left(\theta\right)}\left[w\cos{\left(\theta\right)}+\sin{\left(\theta\right)}\right]\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}{w^{2}\cos^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}+\cos^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}}\\
&~~~~~\times\left[\arctan{\left(\frac{w\cos{\left(\theta\right)}+2\sin{\left(\theta\right)}}{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}\right)}-\arctan{\left(w\right)}\right];~~~\small{\left[v=w\cos{\left(\theta\right)}\right]}\\
&=\cos{\left(\theta\right)}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{2w+2\tan{\left(\theta\right)}}{w^{2}+1}\left[\arctan{\left(w+2\tan{\left(\theta\right)}\right)}-\arctan{\left(w\right)}\right]\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+\tan^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{w+\tan{\left(\theta\right)}}{w^{2}+1}\left[\arctan{\left(w+2\tan{\left(\theta\right)}\right)}-\arctan{\left(w\right)}\right]\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+z^{2}}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{w+z}{w^{2}+1}\left[\arctan{\left(w+2z\right)}-\arctan{\left(w\right)}\right];~~~\small{\left[z=\tan{\left(\theta\right)}\right]}\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+z^{2}}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{w+z}{w^{2}+1}\int_{w}^{w+2z}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{x^{2}+1}\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+z^{2}}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{w+z}{w^{2}+1}\int_{0}^{2z}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{\left(w+y\right)^{2}+1};~~~\small{\left[x=w+y\right]}\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+z^{2}}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}w\int_{0}^{2z}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{w+z}{w^{2}+1}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(w+y\right)^{2}+1}\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+z^{2}}}\int_{0}^{2z}\mathrm{d}y\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{w+z}{\left(w^{2}+1\right)\left[\left(w+y\right)^{2}+1\right]}.\\
\end{align}$$

Given fixed but arbitrary $y\in\mathbb{R}$, the following partial fraction decompositions hold for all $w\in\mathbb{R}$:

$$\frac{y\left(y^{2}+4\right)}{\left(w^{2}+1\right)\left[\left(w+y\right)^{2}+1\right]}=\frac{2\left(w+y\right)+y}{\left(w+y\right)^{2}+1}-\frac{2w-y}{w^{2}+1},$$

$$\frac{y\left(y^{2}+4\right)w}{\left(w^{2}+1\right)\left[\left(w+y\right)^{2}+1\right]}=-\frac{y\left(w+y\right)+\left(y^{2}+2\right)}{\left(w+y\right)^{2}+1}+\frac{yw+2}{w^{2}+1}.$$

Using the fact that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}w\,\left[\frac{\left(w+y\right)}{\left(w+y\right)^{2}+1}-\frac{w}{w^{2}+1}\right]=0;~~~\small{y\in\mathbb{R}},$$

Then,

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{y\left(y^{2}+4\right)}{\left(w^{2}+1\right)\left[\left(w+y\right)^{2}+1\right]}
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}w\,\left[\frac{2\left(w+y\right)+y}{\left(w+y\right)^{2}+1}-\frac{2w-y}{w^{2}+1}\right]\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}w\,\left[\frac{y}{\left(w+y\right)^{2}+1}+\frac{y}{w^{2}+1}\right]\\
&=y\left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{1}{\left(w+y\right)^{2}+1}+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{1}{w^{2}+1}\right]\\
&=y\left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{1}{w^{2}+1}+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{1}{w^{2}+1}\right]\\
&=2y\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{1}{w^{2}+1}\\
&=2y\pi,\\
\end{align}$$

and

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{y\left(y^{2}+4\right)w}{\left(w^{2}+1\right)\left[\left(w+y\right)^{2}+1\right]}
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}w\,\left[-\frac{y\left(w+y\right)+\left(y^{2}+2\right)}{\left(w+y\right)^{2}+1}+\frac{yw+2}{w^{2}+1}\right]\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}w\,\left[\frac{2}{w^{2}+1}-\frac{\left(y^{2}+2\right)}{\left(w+y\right)^{2}+1}\right]\\
&=\left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{2}{w^{2}+1}-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{\left(y^{2}+2\right)}{\left(w+y\right)^{2}+1}\right]\\
&=\left[2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{1}{w^{2}+1}-\left(y^{2}+2\right)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{1}{w^{2}+1}\right]\\
&=-y^{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{1}{w^{2}+1}\\
&=-y^{2}\pi,\\
\end{align}$$

and hence,

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{w+z}{\left(w^{2}+1\right)\left[\left(w+y\right)^{2}+1\right]}=\frac{\pi\left(2z-y\right)}{\left(y^{2}+4\right)}.$$

Thus,

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(z\right)}
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+z^{2}}}\int_{0}^{2z}\mathrm{d}y\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{w+z}{\left(w^{2}+1\right)\left[\left(w+y\right)^{2}+1\right]}\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+z^{2}}}\int_{0}^{2z}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\pi\left(2z-y\right)}{\left(y^{2}+4\right)}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{1+z^{2}}}\int_{0}^{z}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{2\left(z-t\right)}{t^{2}+1};~~~\small{\left[y=2t\right]}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{1+z^{2}}}\left[2z\int_{0}^{z}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t^{2}+1}-\int_{0}^{z}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{2t}{t^{2}+1}\right]\\
&=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{1+z^{2}}}\left[2z\arctan{\left(z\right)}-\ln{\left(1+z^{2}\right)}\right].\blacksquare\\
\end{align}$$

---

Comment: @DavideVenturelli That's because I omitted the $\frac{\sqrt{1+z^2}}{\pi^2 z}$ normalizing factor out front of the integral to reduce clutter while solving the problem. If you multiply my final result by this factor, it indeed tends asymptotically to $1$. I probably should have made this more clear at the outset.

Comment: Yes, I realized it soon after writing the comment, it was very stupid of me -- sorry! This is indeed quite impressive. I'm still curious how comes that the result is correct even though you started the calculation with a different definition of $arctan(z)$ wrt to the one in my question...

Comment: Also, as I mentioned above, this integral popped out from a Physics problem. Your observation allowed for a smoother exposition of a passage in my paper, and so I'd like to acknowledge you. I see your profile is anonymous, but please feel free to contact me.

Comment: @DavideVenturelli Note the two definitions of the arctangent only disagree on the negative real axis, but we don’t actually need that part of the branch since we can rewrite the integrand as $[\arctan(x)]^2= [\arctan(|x|)]^2$.

Comment: Mmh, even for $u<1$?

Comment: Really, very impressive! (+1) I think it is outstanding to find a closed form in such inevident case.